# Show that every solution of the equation $\frac{dy}{dt}+ay=be^{-ct}$ is any real number that approaches 0 as t approaches infinity.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that every solution of the equation $\frac{dy}{dt}+ay=be^{-ct}$ where a and c are positive constants and b is any real number
approaches 0 as t approaches infinity.

$$\frac{dy}{dt}+ay=be^{-ct}$$

so $a(t)=a$

$$μ(t)=e^{\int a(t)dt}$$
$$μ(t)=e^{\int adt}$$
$$μ(t)=e^{at}$$

Multiplying both side of the original equation by $μ(t)$:

$$μ(t)\left[\frac{dy}{dt}+ay\right]=μ(t)[be^{-ct}]$$
$$e^{at}\left[\frac{dy}{dt}+ay\right]=e^{at}[be^{-ct}]$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{at}y)=e^{at-ct}b$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{at}y)=e^{t(a-c)}b$$
$$e^{at}y=\int e^{(a-c)t}bdt$$
$$e^{at}y=b\int e^{(a-c)t}dt$$
$$e^{at}y=\frac{be^{(a-c)t}}{a-c}+C$$
$$y=\frac{1}{e^{at}}\left[\frac{be^{(a-c)t}}{a-c}+C\right]$$
$$y=\frac{1}{e^{at}}\left[\frac{be^{at}e^{-ct}}{a-c}+C\right]$$
$$y=\frac{be^{-ct}}{a-c}+C$$
$$y=\frac{b}{e^{ct}(a-c)}+C$$

As t approaches infinity, $e^{ct}$ blows up and so y goes to 0

Does my work look correct?

Comment: are there any restriction/constraints on $a, b, c?$

Comment: Well a and c are positive and b is any real number, so $e^ct$ will go to infinity if a-c>0 right? But I guess if a-c<0 then....it wold go to negative infinity? Is that right? But isn't 1/-infinity still 0?

Comment: Shouldn't $C$ become $Ce^{-at}$ when brought out of the brackets?

Comment: Oh you're right, and then that also goe to 0 as t goes to infinity

Comment: i don't think you need to all this work. use the fact the homogeneous solution goes to zero as $t\to\infty$ and one particluar which is a multiple of $e^{-ct}$ goes to zero too as $t \to \infty.$ these two facts are enough to argue that all solutions go to zero.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I can just say that the since the homogeneous equation and this particular equation both go to 0 that all solutions must go to 0? If I were to include all this work though, it wouldn't be wrong though would it?

Comment: @abel: I bet there is a chapter on integrating factors involved here.

Comment: @robjohn Yes you're right this came from a chapter where we learned about integrating factors

Comment: @MathMajor: your answer is fine, but what abel says is also true since a general solution to a linear equation is a particular solution plus a constant multiple of the homogeneous solution.

Comment: @robjohn, hi. i don't get what you are saying. i am thinking of the method of undetermined coefficients. no integrating factor at all.

Comment: @MathMajor, your answer is fine. but you can argue the way i outlined too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the cases when $a=c$ and $a\neq c$. When $a\neq c$, then you can integrate, in the other case not.

Answer (score 0):

As the ode is linear we have $y=y_h+y_p$ with

$$
\cases{
\dot y_h + a y_h = 0\\
\dot y_p + a y_p = b e^{-ct}
}
$$

so $y_h = c_1 e^{-a t}$. Now proposing $y_p = c_1(t)e^{-at}$ after substitution we have

$$
\dot c_1(t) e^{-a t} = b e^{-c t}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)
$$

so

$$
c_1(t) = \frac{b}{a-c}e^{(a-c)t}
$$

so $y_p = \frac{b}{a-c}e^{(a-c)t}e^{-a t} =  \frac{b}{a-c}e^{-c t}$ and then

$$
y = y_h+y_p = c_1 e^{-a t} + \frac{b}{a-c}e^{-c t}
$$

NOTE

If $a = c$ the equation $(*)$ will read

$$
\dot c_1(t) e^{-a t} = b e^{-a t}\Rightarrow\ \ \dot c_1(t) = b \Rightarrow \ c_1(t) = b t
$$

and then the solution

$$
y = (c_1+b t)e^{-a t}
$$

In both cases $\lim_{t\to\infty}y=0$